# Using WCF to return a List from a different class

Tags: c#, wcf

I am creating a WCF service that will allow remote management to one of my server applications.

This server application contains a list of connected clients (their address info) which I wish to get hold of using WCF.

When I created my service it created two files, a class, and an interface to that class.

The class which was generated I cannot use because it does not contain the list, my Server application's "Server" class is the one which contains this list.

So I have implemented this interface in my "Server" class and added the relevant code to return a list of addresses of the clients.

This is my first time using WCF and I have a feeling I am doing it wrong.

As written above, what is the correct way of accessing a list in another class which isn't a part of the service?

Thanks.

How I have implemented the service:

```
class MyServer : IMonitorService
{
```

How I have hosted the service:

```
ServiceHost myHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyServer));

myHost.Open();
```

GetClientList:

```
    public List<string> GetClientList()
    {
        List<string> clientStringList = new List<string>();
        lock (ClientList) 
        {
            foreach (ClientHandle client in ClientList)
            {
                clientStringList.Add(client.ClientAddress);
            }
        }
        return clientStringList;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

in your interface

```
List<myClass> send();
```

and in your class:

```
List<myClass> send(){

List<myClass> myList = new List<myClass>();

 return myList;
```

}

In this way you can use your wcf service to return any class list